# Trying to dynamically create a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector of Strings that I wish to use as column headers for a data frame.

Example: cols <- c("A: Ike (N=428)", "F: Mike (N=691)", "G: Bike (N=380)", "Total (N=1499)", "p value")

I have a list of lists of lists of Strings that I want to add as the data from my data frame.

Example, 1st three rows:

```
[[1]] [[1]]$Female [[1]]$Female[[1]] [1] "151"   "35.3%"

[[1]]$`Age in Years` [[1]]$`Age in Years`[[1]] NULL

[[1]]$`Mean (SD)` [[1]]$`Mean (SD)`[[1]] [1] "59.7" "11.4"

[[2]] [[2]]$Female [[2]]$Female[[1]] [1] "280"   "40.5%"

[[2]]$`Age in Years` [[2]]$`Age in Years`[[1]] NULL

[[2]]$`Mean (SD)` [[2]]$`Mean (SD)`[[1]] [1] "60.3" "11.6"

[[3]] [[3]]$Female [[3]]$Female[[1]] [1] "152" "40%"

[[3]]$`Age in Years` [[3]]$`Age in Years`[[1]] NULL

[[3]]$`Mean (SD)` [[3]]$`Mean (SD)`[[1]] [1] "59.8" "11.5"

[[4]] [[4]]$Female [[4]]$Female[[1]] [1] "583"   "38.9%"

[[4]]$`Age in Years` [[4]]$`Age in Years`[[1]] NULL

[[4]]$`Mean (SD)` [[4]]$`Mean (SD)`[[1]] [1] "60"   "11.5"

[[5]] [[5]]$Female [[5]]$Female[[1]] [1] "0.190"

[[5]]$`Age in Years` [[5]]$`Age in Years`[[1]] [1] "0.614"
```

IOW, I want a data frame where column 1 is called names[1] and consists of frameLists[[1]].

Per the suggestions below, I changed my code to the following:

```
outFrame <- do.call(data.frame, c(frameLists, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
colnames(outFrame) <- cols
```

Results come back looking like this:

```
  A: Ike (N=428) F: Mike (N=691) G: Bike (N=380) Total (N=1499) p value   NA     NA   NA    NA    NA 
1            151            59.7             280           60.3     152 59.8    583   60 0.190 0.614 
2          35.3%            11.4           40.5%           11.6     40%  1.5  38.9% 11.5 0.190 0.614
```

The results I want:

```
  A: Ike (N=428) F: Mike (N=691) G: Bike (N=380) Total (N=1499) p value
1     151, 35.3%      280, 40.5%        152, 40%     583, 38.9%   0.190
2                                                                 0.614
3     59.7, 11.4      60.3, 11.6      59.8, 11.5       60, 11.5
```

Comment: What is `names`? please post output of names

Comment: You're actually trying to create a column dynamically, not a dataframe. Does the dataframe frameLists have a column called '1'? Try frameLists[which] with single square bracket.

Comment: `names` and `which` are R functions. Try to avoid using function names as object names, it's confusing.

Comment: @MaxPD frameLists is a list of lists.  The individual lists are unnamed. When I start I don't know how many columns there will be, how many rows there will be, or what the column names are. IMO that's "creating a data.frame dynamically"

Comment: Is that really the sample result that you want, or your currently result? It will help to show the desired, rather than current, result

Comment: That's the results coming back, which are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built the following to meet my needs.  It's clunky, but so far it works.  First: the output:

```
> myDF
             A: Ike (N=428)   F: Mike (N=691) G: Bike (N=380) Total (N=1499) p value
Female           151, 35.3%        280, 40.5%        152, 40%     583, 38.9%   0.190
Age in Years                                                                   0.614
Mean (SD)        59.7, 11.4        60.3, 11.6      59.8, 11.5       60, 11.5        
Q1, Q3               53, 68            52, 69          52, 68         52, 68        
Range                27, 88            19, 88          26, 85         19, 88
```

Now the code that generated it:

```
#' Make a data.frame given the column headers and data to fill the data.frame
#' 
#' @param cols          Vector of text holding the column names
#' @param frameLists    List of lists holding the data for the data frame.  First list element 
#' must have all the names used in frameLists. Must be as many lists in frameLists as there are 
#' Strings in cols
#' @returnType  Data Frame
#' @return  Data Frame with all the elements set up and filled in
buildFrame <- function (cols, frameLists) {
    outList <- list()
    for (col in cols) {
        outList[[col]] <- NA
    }

    outFrame = data.frame(outList, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    colnames(outFrame) <- cols

    outList <- list()
    for (col in cols) {
        outList[[col]] <- list()
    }

    theNames <- names(frameLists[[1]])
    whichCol <- 1
    for (topList in frameLists) {
        colList <- outList[[whichCol]]
        for (aName in theNames) {
            data <- topList[[aName]]
            if (is.null(data)) {
                colList[[aName]] <- ""
            }
            else {
                colList[[aName]] <- data
            }
        }
        outList[[whichCol]] <- colList
        whichCol <- whichCol + 1
    }

    outFrame <- rbind(outList, outFrame)
    outFrame <- outFrame[-1 - length(theNames), ]
    rownames(outFrame) <- theNames

    return(outFrame)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all the lists have equal number of string inside, try

```
result <- do.call(data.frame, c(lapply(frameLists, unlist), stringsAsFactors=F))
names(result) <- name
```

Example data of list of lists (not sure if this is what you meant, please provide sample data otherwise) and vector of name

```
frameLists <- list(list(c("asd", "faf"), NULL, c("3", "2")), list(c("aaa", "zzz"),NULL, c("1", "3")), list(c("qw", "gs"), NULL, c("3", "2")))
name <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Output

```
> result
    a   b  c
1 asd aaa qw
2 faf zzz gs
3   3   1  3
4   2   3  2
> str(result)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: chr  "asd" "faf" "3" "2"
 $ b: chr  "aaa" "zzz" "1" "3"
 $ c: chr  "qw" "gs" "3" "2"
```

Another possible interpretation (not sure what output you want) of the same input:

```
res <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lapply(frameLists, function(x) do.call(cbind, x))), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Output is

```
> res
   V1 V2  V3 V4 V5 V6
1 asd  3 aaa  1 qw  3
2 faf  2 zzz  3 gs  2
> str(res)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "asd" "faf"
 $ V2: chr  "3" "2"
 $ V3: chr  "aaa" "zzz"
 $ V4: chr  "1" "3"
 $ V5: chr  "qw" "gs"
 $ V6: chr  "3" "2"
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work.  do.call insists on breaking up all my data.  Even if I make it a list of lists of lists (rather than of vectors), each string goes to its own column

Comment: that's why I illustrated how I created my data, because I'm not sure how your data structure is. "List of lists" was vague. Can you `dput` your current list of lists, so I can adapt the solution?

Comment: also what's your desired output? You seem to only have your current output. I don't know e.g. how you want to treat the NULL in the list.

Comment: I've added my current solution as an answer.  I'm treating NULL / NA as an empty string.  Any feedback you have on my solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because you initialized `results` as an empty data frame, which R takes to be a data frame with 0 rows and 0 columns. When adding a column to a data frame, its number of rows must match the existing frame's. That's why you got the error message `replacement has 2 rows, data has 0`.

It'd easier to bind a list of columns together into a dataframe all at once. Problem is, the `data.frame` function doesn't want a list, it wants each column as a separate argument:

`data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(34,1,1))`.

How can you make `data.frame` take a list of columns rather than multiple arguments?

***That's what `do.call` is for!***

Give `do.call` a function and a list of args, and it deals the args to the function one at a time.

```
colList <- list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(34,1,1))
col_names <- c('a','b','c')
df <- do.call(data.frame,colList)
colnames(df) <- col_names
```

Result:

```
> df
  a b  c
1 1 4 34
2 2 5  1
3 3 6  1
```

Works equally well if colList is a list of vectors of strings, but you may want to use `stringsAsFactors = F` to avoid factor conversion by `data.frame`.

Comment: You get the green check for your explanation of do.call.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually this doesn't work.  do.call insists on breaking up all my data.  Even if I make it a list of lists of lists (rather than of vectors), each string goes to its own column

Comment: Your data structure appears to be much more complicated than this code can handle (frankly overcomplicated). Is that mess shown in your post the raw R printout? I still can't tell what the data structure actually is. I think it might be missing some carriage returns.

Comment: @GregDougherty at this point I think your best move is to look at your data and where it came from, so we can plan a better strategy. What does the original source look like, before it was turned into a convoluted list of list of list whatevers? Does it have a more readable format which you could paste into the question? If not, could you at least paste the output of `str(frameLists)`? That would show the exact structure of `frameLists` very explicitly.

Comment: Data that I'm massaging is a bunch of strings, organized as Pandoc output to represent a table.  I'm getting the data one row at a time. Given a choice, I'd rather build the data frame after I have everything

Comment: I've added my current solution as an answer. I'm treating NULL / NA as an empty string. Any feedback you have on my solution would be appreciated